# Monodevelop lost design and widget access

Tags: monodevelop

Using monodevelop on Ubuntu using GTK# and lost access to the design window and widgets, how do I get them back please? I have previously used  Visual Studio and, separately wxWidgets, so used to programming with GUIs

Comment: I do not have the solution of your problem, but I wanted to take the opportunity to recommend you a better IDE for developing C# for Unity. https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/ is a paid IDE but the Early Access Program is free. https://www.jetbrains.com/resources/eap/

Comment: @Kuruchy while Rider is clearly a better option, it does not have a designer for GTK# applications.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the info, I didn't know it wasn't posible.